# Android app SocketTimeoutException after 300000ms when smartwatch is not connected via usb cable to PC

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp, wear-os, connection-timeout

I have an app on smartwatch (Wear OS) which is listening for events on server-sent events endpoint running on my local PC. Smartwatch and PC are on the same network (subnet is the same). I can access the service from my mobile phone browser, which is on the same network.
The app is able to connect to end-point when the smartwatch is connected via USB cable to the PC in debug mode, but once I detach it from the cable no events arrived caused by SocketTimeoutException. I tried to increase the timeout, but with no luck.
I keep getting this kind of exception. The strange thing is what actually the smartwatch IP wlan is 192.168.1.116 but when it is disconnected from the USB it seems to be changed to 192.168.167.239, the port number is changing with every log printout.
the service is on nodejs, using server-sent events.
The firewall is disabled. The WLAN connection is private. OS Windows 10.
I use the OKhttp3 library to establish the connection.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build();
    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding","identity")
            .addHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream");
```

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.109 (port 8081) from /192.168.167.239 (port 55586) after 300000ms:
the end-point is 192.168.1.109:8081

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that these are distinct networks, and that you can't connect between them. Perhaps try a service like https://ngrok.com/ to give you a public address to try to connect to.

Comment: Well, thanks, this could be a workaround. Limited and kind of unsecured. I was wondering though why it become a different network once I disconnect the smartwatch from the USB cable only and when it is connected it works fine.

Comment: To dig into this you would likely need to look at what networks are activated at each moment. I have a nework wear app with a tile that can show the networks if it helps.  I can give you access to the private github repo if you want to try it.  What watch is it? And are 192.168.1 and 192.168.167 the networks you expect?

Comment: I've tried on 2 smartwatches, Oppo Watch and TicWatch S2, the behavior is the same. The test have been done on TicWatch though, the IP done by my modem to the smartwatch have been 192.168.1.109 from what i can see in the watch network settings. ADB in Android studio is showing it on 192.168.1.109:5555. Once the service was down and i saw from the log that the connection the smartwatch have been trying to establish was from 192.168.1.109. But once i disconnect it from the USB cable seems like inside the application the IP become 192.168.167.239 for an unknown for me reason.

Comment: on ADB it keep connection on 192.168.1.109 though, because I can still see the log.

Comment: It's probably worth understanding what 192.168.167.x is.  Does it show in the system settings as the Wifi network address?

Comment: What happens if you enable Wifi ADB debugging? Does it then allow you to connect to 192.168.1.109?

Comment: i have no clue where the 192.168.167.239 coming from (btw it is always the same at least so far). WiFi ADB debugging is enabled, otherwise, I would not be able to see the Android studio log. today it's 192.168.1.116, so from the And Studio I can see like this: C:\UC-B>adb devices
List of devices attached
8605X06050017   device
192.168.1.116:5555      device

Comment: if u can help me understand what is going on with the IPs I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: i really need a solution to stay on local network. Using ngrok i need to recompile every time the app to update the network settings. And this is not good solution for smartwatch application. @Yuri Schimke, would u give me an access to the app u mentioned in the previous post?

Comment: What is your github account?

Comment: my nickname is Miliks