# Android WearOS app SocketTimeoutException failing to connect to a local server when bluetooth connected

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am developing a smartwatch app which connects to an API and make requests. The thing is, when I try to connect to the server and my phone is not connected to the watch, it works well and it connects to my local pc serving a rails API in 192.168.1.132:3000. The problem comes when the watch is connected to the phone via bluetooth. I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.victorrubia.tfg, PID: 5079
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.132 (port 3000) from /192.168.167.239 (port 37933) after 10000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.kt:63)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I can't understand how is possible the watch is connecting well to my server when it is only connected via WIFI and when it is also paired with the phone it cannot connect to my server. The smartwatch I am using is a TicWatch 3 connected via ADB WIFI.

I have tried to make a GET request to a remote domain such as google.com and it performs well in both cases (connected only to WIFI and WIFI+Bluetooth) so I would really appreciate if anyone could help me sort this out.

PD: I have also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679830/android-app-sockettimeoutexception-after-300000ms-when-smartwatch-is-not-connect) but no solution was provided.

Comment: Can your phone connect to the same network?

Comment: Yes it does, in fact it seems to be something with the phone proxying wear’s requests with local IP’s. I’ve looking for it and I couldn’t find much information. It seems when wear is connected to the phone via Bluetooth it expects connections to remote servers rather than local ones. The only workaround I found is to force the connection via WiFi when available [as mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/network-access) (at the moment it always be as I’m developing and trying the app at home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the failure to connect specifically to local addresses over bluetooth, but you can request a specific network and set it as the default.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2404

or specify it using a socketfactory

https://programmer.ink/think/the-implementation-of-okhttp-multi-network-communication.html

```
                public void onAvailable(final Network network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network);
                    //After the network is connected
                    SocketFactory socketFactory = network.getSocketFactory();
                    //If you use the eclipse MQTT package, you need to set the
                    mqttConnectOptions.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);
                    //If you use regular network connection, okhttp, you need to set
                    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                            //.proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
                            .socketFactory(socketFactory)
                            .dns(new Dns() {
                                @Override
                                public List<InetAddress> lookup(@NonNull String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
                                    return Arrays.asList(network.getAllByName(hostname));
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
```